# Vim autocompletion word with character _ , in python and latex

Tags: vim, autocomplete, latex, supertab

In vim, I managed to have autocompletion installing Supertab. 
When I work on a .py file, it works ok: I can autocomplete `xxx_yyy` by typing `xxTAB` (and it pops up options if many `xxx_yyy1` `xxx_yyy2` exist).

But on a **.tex file**, if I have already the word `xxx_yyy`, when I type `xxTAB` I get the only match `xxx`.

How can I match `xxx_yyy` with `xxTAB` in a .tex file too?

This is my .vimrc :

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set backspace=indent,eol,start
autocmd Filetype python setlocal expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
set ww=<,>,[,]
```

Comment: I don’t know Supertab but the LaTeX behaviour is correct, since in LaTeX `foo_bar` *isn’t* one word: `_` is not valid in macro names, and in general it’s a special character that adds subscript in math mode (and creates an error in normal mode, which is unfortunate).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph : I find it useful to retrieve for example all the figure names when referencing them with the `\label{}` : `\ref{fig_bla1}` Vs `\ref{fig_bla2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SuperTab uses the built-in *insert mode completion* (`:help i_CTRL-N`), and that is based on *keywords*. This setting is filetype-specific, controlled by the `'iskeyword'` option. For Python, the `_` is included, for Latex, it isn't (and based on @Konrad Rudolph's comment, for a reason).

You can certainly adapt this if it bothers you. In your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd Filetype tex setlocal iskeyword+=_
```